# WordPress: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2 bytes)

Tags: wordpress

Alguém sabe como resolver esse erro? Já configurei o arquivo wp-admin.php e o .htaccess, mas continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: também já enviei o arquivo php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código pode estar em loop infinito, causando consumo elevado dos recursos do servidor. Outro motivo que causa isso é uma página com muitas imagens com caminho do arquivo errado. Você pode tentar aumentar os recursos disponíveis para seu PHP, no arquivo php.ini, procure por:

```
memory_limit = 128M;
```

Aumente para 512 por exemplo e veja se o problema continua.

Também, você pode tentar colocar isso no seu config.php:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Tente achar o motivo do alto consumo. Reinicie o servidor após as alterações. Caso você utilize cPanel na sua hospedagem, a alteração dos limites de memória deve ser feita por lá.

Comment: Eu adicionei o ";" no final de cada instrução no arquivo php.ini, coloquei  "ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');" no wp-config.php. E não resolveu. Minha hospedagem é compartilhada, não posso reiniciar o servidor.  Eu só não consigo entrar no Admin. o site está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Sua hospedagem utiliza Cpanel?

Comment: Utiliza cPanel  sim.

Comment: Então é por meio do cpanel que você fará a alteração no limite de memória.

Comment: @Stéfano porque links quebrados causam alto consumo de memória?

Comment: Eu me expressei mal, são as imagens com caminho de arquivo quebrado.